# Get last version of all keys in hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am trying the following:

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setMaxVersion(1);
```

And after I iterate on the result I don't get the last version of the keys.

If I set the `maxVersion` to 1, should it return the last version, right?

Comment: Do you mean latest version by the last version ?

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below function which will get the latest of version of each column

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.readVersions(1);
```

https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#readVersions-int-